# What are the casting rules for numpy datetime units?

Tags: python, numpy, types

For all numpy [ufuncs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) (e.g. `numpy.add`) there exists a `types` property that shows which dtype the result of the operation will have for a given set of input dtypes.

For `datetime64` and `timedelta64` the specification seems ambiguous however as it does not contain the units of the result.

One can of course find out what the units of the dtype of the operation result are by running test-cases through it but is there a more general way of determining the units?

I.e. is there a general purpose way to determine the units of the dtype if I e.g. add `datetime64(unit='D')` and `timedelta64(unit='s')`?

Is there a numpy function to which I can feed the dtypes of my inputs and get the result dtype?